# Deploying Postgres and keycloak container in kubernetes, error in the yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

this is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.3
        args: ["start-dev"]
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        - name: KC_PROXY
          value: "edge"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /realms/master
            port: 8080
      - name: postgres
          image: postgres:latest
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

when i run "kubectl create -f file.yaml i get the following error: error parsing keycloak.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 36: mapping values are not allowed in this context

I have tried to put my yaml file in a YAML Linters and i got the following output:
Multiple documents detected - Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings at line 50, column 15
Implicit keys need to be on a single line at line 50, column 15
Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings at line 51, column 18
Implicit keys need to be on a single line at line 51, column 18
All mapping items must start at the same column at line 53, column 1
All mapping items must start at the same column at line 55, column 1
All mapping items must start at the same column at line 58, column 1

Answer (score 0):

You had a problem with identation. here's the updated YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.3
        args: ["start-dev"]
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        - name: KC_PROXY
          value: "edge"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /realms/master
            port: 8080
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:latest
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5432
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: postgres-config
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
            name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```